# How do we print loop output in single line?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
class GFG {
public static void main (String[] args)
 {
    int t,num;

    //read input
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    t = scanner.nextInt();

    while(t>0) {
        t--;
        num = scanner.nextInt();
        for(int i=2;i<=num;i++) {
          primeNumbers(i);  

        }
    }
 }

 public static void primeNumbers(int num) {

        int count=2;
        while(count<num) {
         if(num%count==0) {
            return;
         }
         count++;
     } 
     System.out.print(num+" ");
 }
```

}

For Input:

2: No. of test cases i.e. t

10 : num

35 : num

Your Output is:

2 3 5 7 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31

But I want to get Output like below:

2 3 5 7

2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a print of a new line after for loop calling  `primeNumbers`

```
for(int i=2;i<=num;i++) {
    primeNumbers(i);  
}
System.out.print("\n"); // or System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple: by calling *println()* to insert a newline at the right place, for example after the *for* loop within the while loop in your main method.

That is all there is to this.